# How do I choose tabs to include in MultiExec of MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm

By default all open tabs are included in the MultiExec.
While inside MultiExec environment I can check a box to exclude a tab.
Is there a clever way to choose the tabs to be included in the MultiExec environment to begin with?
I am always scared of accidentally running a command in production.

Comment: I know this is not the question here but I'd rather stop using this in production. It resulted in many accidental incidents in our company. Use Ansible instead to run commands on multiple nodes.

Comment: Thank you @TonyStark i agree that this is ultimatum correct answer.